# Xml without indent char but with new line

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

Is there a way to write xml using boost::property_tree, without indent characters but with new line?

Consider this code

```
using namespace boost::property_tree;
int main() {
    ptree tree;
    ptree* root = &tree.add("root", "");
    root->add("something", "yes");
    root->add("something2", "no");
    write_xml("test.xml", tree, std::locale(), xml_writer_settings<ptree::key_type>('\n', 0));
}
```

When indent_count is set to 0, we get this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><something>yes</something><something2>no</something2></root>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<something>yes</something>
<something2>no</something2>
</root>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this without adding '\n' through file manipulation?
I'm using boost 1_66.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you cannot do this.
Take a look at: https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/d30ff9404bd6af5cc8922a177865e566f4846b19/include/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_write.hpp#L76

```
bool want_pretty = settings.indent_count > 0;
```

and then, at 101 line:

```
if (want_pretty)
     stream << Ch('\n');
```

So, if you want to have new line delimiters, ya have to have one or more indenting chars in the settings.

Comment: ahh I see, so I'm left with manually adding those '\n'. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: You're left with using an XML library. Property Tree is not an XML library.

Comment: @sehe sadly my coworkers are not too willing to add proper xml library. don't know why tho